# How to pass parameters to FromSqlRaw?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
using(DAD_BaldipContext ctx = new DAD_BaldipContext())
{
    int month = 02;
    int year = 2018;
    var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlRaw("TotalMonthlyRental @month, @year", month, year).ToList();

    textbox.Text = x[1].TruckId.ToString();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TotalMonthlyRental] 
    @month int, 
    @year int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT MONTH(RentDate) AS Month, SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalRental
    FROM [TruckRental-PB]
    WHERE MONTH(RentDate) = @month
      AND YEAR(RentDate) = @year
    GROUP BY MONTH([RentDate]), YEAR(RentDate)
END
```

I am trying to call this stored procedure called `TotalMonthlyRental` which requires two parameters month and year.

I have hard coded a month and year however I am getting the error must declare the scalar variable month.

Answer (score 9):

In FromSqlRaw you can either construct DbParameter objects,

```
int month = 02;
int year = 2018;
var pMonth = new SqlParameter("@month", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
var pYear = new SqlParameter("@year", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

pMonth.Value = month;
pYear.Value = year;

var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlRaw("exec TotalMonthlyRental @month, @year;", pMonth, pYear).ToList();
```

or use a format-style string.

```
int month = 02;
int year = 2018;
var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlRaw("exec TotalMonthlyRental {0}, {1};", month, year).ToList();
```

Notice that there's no ambiguity as you are passing a format string and additional arguments, so EF knows to parameterize the query.

Also you can use [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-5.0) which handles the parameterization for you if your query is an interpolated string:

```
int month = 02;
int year = 2018;
var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec TotalMonthlyRental {month}, {year};").ToList();
```

If you passed that interpolated string to FromSqlRaw the string interpolation would happen before the query is passed in and it wouldn't be parameterized.

Comment: var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlRaw("exec TotalMonthlyRental @month, @year;", pMonth, pYear).ToList();
In this case make sure what parameters are placed in the right order. 
Despite the first SqlParameter argument (@month, @year), swapping month and year in fromSqlRow won't work. I mean:

Comment: var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlRaw("exec TotalMonthlyRental @month, @year;",  pYear, pMonth).ToList();

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Perhaps if you have a question you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need exec in your statement. Use this:

```
int month = 02;
int year = 2018;

var x = ctx.TruckRentalPb.FromSqlInterpolated($"TotalMonthlyRental {month}, {year}").AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Also, AsNoTracking() may be beneficial for reads from the database and saves another 30% or so in execution time.
[Check this blog entry from c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-and-asnotracking/)

Another note: make sure your variables are in the exact same order as they are in your stored procedure.